# How can I get a menu with vertical text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I'm trying to get a menu with vertical text like on the image bellow
[image: vertical menu]

I'm using Wordpress and Divi builder but it needs to be done with some custom CSS.
I tried something like this:

```
#mobile_menu_slide a {
    width: 1em;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 40px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

and got this:
[image]

now I don't know how to align them like on the first picture.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried giving `#mobile_menu_slide` a `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: This is a ux disaster. Who designs stuff like this?!

Comment: we are staying with the horizontal menu because it's not user-friendly at all. Just some crazy designer ideas. :D thank you very much for the answer :)